# QRCode reader n iphone

Tags: iphone, qr-code

I want to read(Decode) the generated QRcode.
I had found the link for encoding the QRCODE in github.But didnt get the link or anything from where i can decode the generated qrcode.I had gone through zbar and Zxing.But it is not working properly.
And   [this](http://www.bardecode.com/en/products/200-barcode-reader-sdk-for-the-iphone.html) is not free licence.i want something which is free licensed and can encode and decode the code properly.
Can any one please help me out.

Comment: ZXing works perfectly fine, as demonstrated [here](http://zxing.appspot.com/generator/) it maybe the case that you can't get it working.

Comment: "it is not working properly" doesn't tell us anything about the problem. I doubt Zxing is actually broken, as many people seem to be using it successfully. So, figure out *how* and *why* it's not working and fix it or ask for help if you're stuck.

Comment: @Zasz thanks for the link.I had already gone through this.But can u give me the link for the guide where do i get source code to decode the QR.

Comment: @Caleb thanks for the reply.u where also newbie once.n such type of question where asked many times.So u can't write that this type of question should not be asked..

Comment: @shweta Why Zbar not works? I'm using it and seems that works well.

Comment: @Mat From where did u get the zbar code??

Comment: @Caleb Thanks for the comment.its better u first read the question and then to comment.I had already wrote that i want something to decode.I had code to encode.But i m not getting any thing form where to start the code for decoding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [QR code and barcode reader in iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687252/qr-code-and-barcode-reader-in-iphone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [ZBar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/files/iPhoneSDK/ZBarSDK-1.2.dmg/download) and read the [docs](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/), it's very easy to use, you can [scan from image](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/tutorial.html), or [scan from camera feed](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/camera.html). Also you can use free [generator online](http://zxing.appspot.com/generator/) to test your apps.

EDIT:
For encode you could call the [Google Chart Api](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) like this if you want for example a qr code iamge that contains the link www.google.com (so just replace the link with your data, 300x300 is the size):

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl=www.google.com&chld=H|0
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.I get the code to encode it.But i m not getting anything to decode.Please help me to decode the Generater QR code..

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mat.I got the solution from zbar.

Answer (score 2):

You can browse the zxing code online here and checkout it and also download it here :

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/checkout

You can also try out this project started by one of my colleague in thoughtworks :

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/qrcode.aspx

Since these are in java and .net Im not sure if they will be useful to you because you mentioned iPhone in your title. ZXing in addition to the main java codebase has a pretty good C# port, and it works for me with a little bit of tinkering around with the code to suit my machine.

Zxing also works on iPhone because they have an app around their library called "barcodes" It is very fast, open source and it is your best bet.

Also [onbarcode](http://www.onbarcode.com/products/iphone_barcode/barcodes/qrcode.html) is also a good option and I know a few people who used it with success. Documentation exists albiet a bit poor.

Comment: @Zasc thank u very much. i had gone through the onBarCode it is working very well.But it is not providing free license.And other two link which u had give is not showing code for iphone.I know it is possible to do decoding of QR code.But my question is how to do that in iphone

Comment: zxing has code for iPhone : [http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk%2Fiphone](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk%2Fiphone)